# Is there a roadmap for Apache Ignite 2.x to adopt Cassandra Java Driver 4.x and enable seamless Cassandra integration for future updates?

Tags: cassandra, integration, ignite

1. Apache Cassandra 4.x has been released, does Apache Ignite intends to incorporate Cassandra Java driver 4.x for seamless integration with Apache Cassandra 4.x. As of now, Apache Ignite version 2.15.0 is still using Cassandra Java driver 3.2.0, What are the plans to upgrade it to version 4.x to ensure compatibility and leverage the latest features and improvements.
2. Is there a roadmap for Apache Ignite 3.x to incorporate support for external storage integration, such as RBDB and NoSQL databases?

Comment: You should ask this on the developer's mail list - dev@ignite.apache.org https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ignite/site/ignite-6036/community/resources.html